# R - Selecting Top Records but With a Grouping

Tags: r

Using the Iris dataframe I can pretty easily pull the first n = 100 records with:

```
m_data<-iris
m_data[1:100,]
```

But I am also interested in pulling the first 100 records based on a nice split of the Species. Assume for the moment that the first 100 records are all the same species - I would like to pull the data with a "first sampling" based on the varying Species instead.

Any suggestions are welcome. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternative:

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(split(iris, iris$Species), head, 100))
```

This pulls the first 100 records from `iris` by `Species`

You can use `by` instead of `lapply`

```
do.call(rbind, by(iris, iris$Species, head, 100))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this with `dplyr`, here selecting the first 10 from each species:

```r
library(dplyr)
iris %>%
  group_by(Species) %>%
  filter(row_number() <= 10) # or slice(1:10)
#> # A tibble: 30 x 5
#> # Groups:   Species [3]
#>    Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
#>           <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl> <fct>  
#>  1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2 setosa 
#>  2          4.9         3            1.4         0.2 setosa 
#>  3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2 setosa 
#>  4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2 setosa 
#>  5          5           3.6          1.4         0.2 setosa 
#>  6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4 setosa 
#>  7          4.6         3.4          1.4         0.3 setosa 
#>  8          5           3.4          1.5         0.2 setosa 
#>  9          4.4         2.9          1.4         0.2 setosa 
#> 10          4.9         3.1          1.5         0.1 setosa 
#> # ... with 20 more rows
```

Created on 2018-08-13 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).